# How to dowload a private file from S3 bucket through API

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am uploading a private file from localhost to Amazon S3. After uploading, how to download that particular file from front end.(JavaScript)

Answer (score 2):

You can try s3.getObject

some links that can help You:
https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/

Examples:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/e6671c4340d54010fb7dcf2eaebd679f565bf51b/ts/s3.ts

Comment: Do s3.getObject download a file or returns a response with JSON?

Comment: if you need file on your file system then you should use something like this: s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file)

Comment: Ok Cool, thanks but I don't want to download it from node. So, is there any way I can download it from front end?

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly write(C#) code to download private file as string

   ```
    public string DownloadPrivateFileS3(string fileKey)
    {
        string accessKey = "YOURVALUE";
        string accessSecret = "YOURVALUE";;
        string bucket = "YOURVALUE";;
        using (s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, accessSecret, "YOURVALUE"))
        {
                var folderPath = "AppData/Websites/Cases";
                var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
                Stream stream = fileTransferUtility.OpenStream(bucket, folderPath + "/" + fileKey);
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                     stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    var response = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(response);
                }

                return "";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Second Write JQuery Code to download string as Base64

```js
function downloadPrivateFile() {
$.ajax({url: 'DownloadPrivateFileS3?fileName=' + fileName, success: function(result){
        var link = this.document.createElement('a');
        link.download = fileName;
        link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + result;
        this.document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        this.document.body.removeChild(link);
  }});
}
```

Call downloadPrivateFile method from anywhere of HTML/C#/JQuery -

Enjoy Happy Coding and Solutions of Complex Problems